# Sequence of complex numbers, having throuble with this problem.

Tags: complex-analysis

The question: Supose $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ with  $\lvert a \rvert = \lvert b\rvert > 1$. If the sequence $\{a^n - b^{n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is limited, prove that a = b.

I was thinking in use the identity $(a^n - b^n) = (a - b)(a^{n - 1} + ... + b^{n - 1})$ to estimate the difference $\lvert a - b \rvert$, but i can't solve this problem....

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $a \neq b$. Prove that if $a = b^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then the sequence does not tend to $0$. If $a \neq b^k$ for any real $k \in \mathbb{N}$ then prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, and any $N \in \mathbb{N}$, you can find $n \geq N$ so that $a^n$ is within angle $\epsilon$ of $b^n$. Then you will have $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a^n - b^n| \neq 0$.